# Update Score Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cclabelttf

Ive been trying to figure out how to update the score. I have an label with a string that the score goes on but it doesn't update

This is the label with the score thats suppose to update

```
score=0;
CCLabelTTF *scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score] fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
scorelabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
scorelabel.color = [CCColor blackColor];
scorelabel.position = ccp(0.85f, 0.95f); // Top Right of screen
[self addChild:scorelabel];
```

Then this is where the score is added after a collision between two sprites

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair monsterCollision:(CCNode *)monster projectileCollision:(CCNode *)projectile {
//Creating another sprite on the position the monster one was.
CCSprite *explosion = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"explosion.png"];
explosion.position = monster.position;
[self addChild:explosion];
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"exsound.mp3"];

CCActionDelay *delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:.0f];
CCActionFadeOut *fade = [CCActionFadeOut actionWithDuration:.4f];
[explosion runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[delay,fade]]];

[monster removeFromParent];
[projectile removeFromParent];

score++;

return YES;
}
```

And advise onto how i could update it because the scoreLabel refuses to update after a collision has been detected

Thank you  :D

Comment: cclabelttf is very slow when the string changes (slow enough to notice a stutter every time the string changes), for frequently updating labels A cclabelbmfont or cclabelatlas are better choices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the score

@Implement (at the very top)

```
CCLabelTTF *scorelabel;
```

Label displaying the Score

```
score=0;
scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:18.0f];
scorelabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
scorelabel.color = [CCColor blackColor];
scorelabel.position = ccp(0.85f, 0.95f); // Top Right of screen
[self addChild:scorelabel];
```

After

```
score++;
```

Write

```
[scorelabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the scoreLabel where you update score.

So after ,

```
 score++;
```

Include

```
[scorelabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score]];
```

Comment: I guess, the scope of scorelabel is restricted to the block where you declared it. In the class where you are using the scorelabel  ,increase its scope by declaring it here @implementation{ CCLabelTTF* scorelabel} . Also replace CCLabelTTF *scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF.... with scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF....

Comment: FINALLY :D thank you very much

its not the "with scorelable" just scorelabel

but thank you very much